# Google web fonts loads lots of extra CSS for other languages, is it safe to delete those?

Tags: css, fonts, google-webfonts

When you pick fonts from google web fonts you get a bunch of different languages it seems:

https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,700

```
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Playfair Display'), local('PlayfairDisplay-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/playfairdisplay/v10/2NBgzUtEeyB-Xtpr9bm1CUR-13DsDU150T1bKbJZejI.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Playfair Display'), local('PlayfairDisplay-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/playfairdisplay/v10/2NBgzUtEeyB-Xtpr9bm1CfoVn-aGdXvQRwgLLg-TkDk.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Playfair Display'), local('PlayfairDisplay-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/playfairdisplay/v10/2NBgzUtEeyB-Xtpr9bm1Cdhy5e3cTyNKTHXrP9DO-Rc.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Playfair Display Bold'), local('PlayfairDisplay-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/playfairdisplay/v10/UC3ZEjagJi85gF9qFaBgIKHabUDGjprROP0Kzi4LtY8.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Playfair Display Bold'), local('PlayfairDisplay-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/playfairdisplay/v10/UC3ZEjagJi85gF9qFaBgILCFnVHHm1VfBoEzRr6gqH0.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Playfair Display Bold'), local('PlayfairDisplay-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/playfairdisplay/v10/UC3ZEjagJi85gF9qFaBgIIsv7neNnoQYDmljOSnH1QE.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215;
}
```

Is loading all these necessary? My website only caters to English speaking users so I rather not load stuff for Latin or Cyrillic speakers and improve performance. Is it safe to remove those? Also if I remove those which one do I keep because in the example above I don't see any for just plain English?

Comment: @LuisP.A.so it looks like "Latin" will always be selected under customize language. But even if I don't select the other 2 (Latin Extended and Cyrillic) they still appear in the css file supplied by google. For example https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Playfair+Display?selection.family=Playfair+Display in customize tab try selecting just "regular 400" and go to the url in the link tag: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400 not sure why cyrillic and latin-ext is there but is it safe to remove those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't use Cyrillic, it's safe to remove the corresponding `@font-face` rule.

But it doesn't hurt either to keep it in: a browser won't download the Cyrillic font if you don't have any Cyrillic characters in your content. It will only be downloaded when you have characters in the Unicode range specified in the `@font-face` rule, in this case:

`unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;`